# SQLAlchemy Query Multiple Relationship Lists

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to create a backend with Flask and SQLAlchemy using a Postgresql database. When setting up the schema in models.py, I have a Card object and a Color object. There are five colors and every card can be multiple colors. As such I'm trying to use a many to many relationship with an Association Object, ColorAssociation. The relevant models.py code is as follows:

```
class ColorAssociation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'color_association'
    card_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cards.id'), primary_key=True)
    color_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('colors.id'), primary_key=True)
    card = db.relationship("Card", back_populates="colors")
    color = db.relationship("Color", back_populates="cards")

class Color(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'colors'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    cards = db.relationship("ColorAssociation", back_populates="color")

class Card(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cards'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    colors = db.relationship("ColorAssociation", back_populates="card")
```

The schema appears to be functioning as after adding some data, I can successfully query for all cards associate with the Color with the name 'Blue' for example by using the following sqlalchemy query:

```
blue = db.session.query(Color).filter(Color.name == 'Blue').all()[0]
for association in blue.cards:
    print(association.card)
```

My question is how to I query for cards of multiple colors? For example, how would I query for all cards that are associated with colors with both the name 'Blue' and 'Green'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I recreated a testing environment and tried to replicate the issue you are having, the common pitfall here is that sqlalchemy provides some heavy lifting in the background. Since you placed associations in another model that must be join onto the table you are query when the logic is a bit more complex. So for example you would like all the cards that are blue or red that's a one liner `db.session.query(Color).filter(or_(color='blue',color='red'))).all()`.

But since you requested that the cards have both colors we need to get all unique cards and add its respective colors. From there we filter the colors that we would like (i.e. Blue and Red in this case). Then make sure that each Card has the same exact number of colors we want. This is accomplished by using the having functionality. Sample below.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import random
from sqlalchemy import and_, func, or_

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class ColorAssociation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'color_association'
    card_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'cards.id'), primary_key=True)
    color_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'colors.id'), primary_key=True)
    card = db.relationship("Card", back_populates="colors")
    color = db.relationship("Color", back_populates="cards")


class Color(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'colors'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    cards = db.relationship("ColorAssociation", back_populates="color")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "< %d, %s>" % (self.id, self.name)


class Card(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cards'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    colors = db.relationship("ColorAssociation", back_populates="card")


db.create_all()
colors_avail = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'orange', 'pink']
for x in colors_avail:
    col = Color(name=x)
    db.session.add(col)
db.session.commit()

for x in range(0, 20):
    card = Card(name=str(x) + "card")
    db.session.add(card)
    db.session.commit()
    colors_id = []
    for randnum in range(1, 6):
        rand = random.randint(1, 5)
        if not rand in colors_id:
            colors_id.append(rand)
    for color_id in colors_id:
        association = ColorAssociation(card_id=card.id, color_id=color_id)
        db.session.add(association)
    db.session.commit()
# Get color ids these are unique in this case
colors = db.session.query(Color).filter(
    or_(Color.name == 'blue', Color.name == 'red')).all()

# Create array of these ids
colors_ids = [color.id for color in colors]

cards = db.session.query(Card).distinct(Card.id).outerjoin(ColorAssociation). \
    filter(ColorAssociation.color_id.in_(colors_ids)).group_by(Card.id).having(
        func.count(ColorAssociation.color_id) == len(colors_ids)).all()
"""
This doesn't work
cards = db.session.query(ColorAssociation). \
    filter(ColorAssociation.color_id.in_(colors_ids)).group_by(ColorAssociation.color_id).having(
        func.count(ColorAssociation.color_id) == len(colors_ids)).all()
"""
for card in cards:
    print(card)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for taking the time to recreate that! Just a question about the last query you do. So the reason I'm trying to use the Association Object is so if I want to filter cards by certain colors, I don't have to check every card in the db (There will be about 30,000) against a color, I can just select the Color and then filter though its cards. Is the last query you do, since it's on Card, checking through every card in the db? If so, is that unavoidable?

Comment: Well the way i would do it is have the card object with a color foreign key, that way I can specify what colors i want. Due to sql having a flat structure. filters(the where) are applied per row and not as a group. There really is not way getting around querying all cards since even color associations have an entry per card you have. And iterating 30,000 rows for a database isn't much even when not properly indexed.